# Unterminated String constant accesdb javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, ms-access

I'm trying this code.

```
var compName = document.getElementById('compNameId').value;
var tranSet = document.getElementById('tranSetId').value;   
var funarea = document.getElementById('funAreaid').value;
var searchTag = document.getElementById('searchTagId').value;
try
{
    var myDB = new ACCESSdb("C:\\Users\\Myname\\Desktop\\Project\\myDatabase.mdb");
    var SQL = "SELECT * FROM AutoDB";
    var resultSet = myDB.query(SQL);
}
catch(ex)
{
    alert(ex.message);
    window.location.href = "form-validation1.htm";
}
```

But I'm receiving the below error.
"unterminated string constant"

I've added the library link as well in the HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/accessdb.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Everywhere I look they say the error message means something is not closed correctly. As it stated in the error message it should be a string but I can't see any issue with your code it could be some other code that is triggering the error.

Comment: Exactly. I can't see any string which is not closed correctly.
I'll take a look at accessdb.js

Comment: Is this all the code? This is a total guess but It also could be what the database is returning. What happens if you comment out the line
var resultSet = myDB.query(SQL);

Comment: It's not showing that error in that case.
But, that's what populates the array with result set.
I can't go ahead without that.

Comment: I understand, but I think that shows the issue is with what is coming back from the database. It's a data issue. I could be wrong about that but that is what it is looking like. Try a different table and test it out.